# Unexpectedly, every other value is being saved twice in loop

Tags: scrape, imacros

I am attempting to scrape the price of items from a website, extracting these values and saving them to CSV, all using iMacros.

I have been successful in creating a looped extraction and save macro, however I am receiving unexpected results. Every second value is being saved twice in the resulting CSV file.

My macro code is as follows:

```
  VERSION BUILD=10022823
    TAB T=1
    TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
    SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
    SET !LOOP 1
    SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\UserName\Documents\URL_List.csv
    SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
    SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
    URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
    SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:preis EXTRACT=TXT
    SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extracted_prices.csv
```

My expected result would be:

```
$99.99
$89.99
$16.99
```

What I am getting is instead:

```
$99.99 
$99.99
89.99 
$16.99 
$16.99
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this behavior is occurring. I have consulted the available documentation on the [iMacros Wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction) to no avail. There are a multitude of existing questions here on stackoverflow that address the creation of data scraping and extraction macros, many of which I have consulted in the creation of the above macro. Nevertheless, I was unable to find anyone experiencing the same difficulty. I also checked the integrity of my CSV file to make sure there hadn't been any errors in it's creation, but I was unable to find any irregularities. Am I just missing something quite simple?

Answer (score 1):

```
 VERSION BUILD=10022823
    TAB T=1
    TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
    SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
    SET !LOOP 1
    SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\UserName\Documents\URL_List.csv
    SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
    SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
    URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
    SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:preis EXTRACT=TXT
    SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extracted_prices.csv
    SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

Maybe you should clear the value of Extract variable.

Comment: Although the documentation [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS) says that the !EXTRACT variable is cleared after the SAVEAS command is called, I did give that a try. Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference. Even more oddly, this error disappeared when I ran the macro via the Firefox extension, rather than in IE as I had originally done. No clue why that might be.

Answer (score 0):

In case my comment gets cleaned up, I'll post my less-than-sufficient "answer".

After toying with this macro and pulling out my hair for a few hours, I switched over from the Internet Explorer extension to the iMacros extension for Firefox et violà, everything worked as expected. However, after running the macro once I received `Error code -1001` upon trying to run. Apparently, this error is caused when the CSV file referenced in `!DATASOURCE` is improperly encoded. CSV files must apparently be saved with UTF-8 encoding.

<s>It's perhaps a long shot, but it is possible that the unexpected results I was receiving in the IE extension were related to encoding.</s> Edit: A quick test resulted in the same output from the IE extension, even after encoding the source CSV as UTF-8.

Hopefully this can be of help to some poor soul!

Comment: Do the same test with IE and see for yourself.

Comment: @macroscripts You've got a good point. I just tried again with a properly encoded UTF-8 CSV file, and IE still produced the same issue. I'm baffled, but glad to have found a "solution" in using the Firefox extension.

Comment: Use FireFox. From personal experience it's the best Browser to go with iMacros. Try also looking for JavaScript solutions. Can I get a rep for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a delay after each loop:

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823

TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\UserName\Documents\URL_List.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

URL GOTO={{!COL1}}

'Wait 5 seconds before extracting
WAIT SECONDS=5

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:preis EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extracted_prices.csv
```

More about the `WAIT` command can be found [here](https://wiki.imacros.net/WAIT).